# c# Delay occurs when pasting large string into RichtextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, paste, large-data

- Observation of Problem

I am a beginner of c# and one RichTextBox in my program is designed to display/input articles, which may contain lots of characters.

However, if pasting a large content into the RTB the program freezes (similar to load from large text files). And It seems like RTB itself is enough to hold an entire article, the only problem is when a chunk of huge string is added to the RTB through clipboard/file directly.

- Attempt to solve the problem:

Text_Changed event:  Never works. It seems like the event will be triggerred only after the string is loaded.

Thus I tried to put string into a buffer and repeatedly read it to the RTB in small chunks before the entire string is pasted to the RTB, and thus I tried to capture the action of paste.

However, some of the solutions about override the WndProc to capture WM_Paste does not apply since WM_Paste does not work to RTB.
So my only approach for now is to disable the shortcut for RTB and simulate the paste behavior by paste() and capture keyevent of ctrl+v, which is apparently naive and I believe there must be some practicle solution for that.

Or maybe the entire idea to solve the problem by loading huge string in small chunks is wrong at all?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: While you are pasting data to the RTB, the RTB parses the Text and looks for Mnemonics to properly adjust the formatting/coloring. This is an all natural behavior for the RTB dealing with huge amount of text. The `Text_Changed event` fires, **after** pasting data to the RTB once. Im missing in your question, **what** you want to achieve

Comment: Hi. The thing is even textbox encounter such issue. Currently I intend to minimize the delay as sometime the entire program freezes after pasting a huge chunk of string.

Comment: You might want to perform your pasting stuff asynchron. So ge GUI-Thread wont freeze over the Pasting-Time